# PayPal Website Payments for Services

Tags: web, paypal, payment

I'm trying to setup PayPal's Website Payments system on my website, where I'm selling services with no shipping!

I'd like to specify for PayPal Checkout to send the payment for me as not for Good, but for Services, so I won't get bound to ship something physical!

My code now: (It's sandbox now)

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="en">
<input type="hidden" name="page_style" value="primary">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="pp_1350857585_biz@zgmail.us">
<!-- <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value=""> -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="TEST">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<!-- <input type="hidden" name="return" value=""> -->
<!-- <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value=""> -->
<!-- <input type="hidden" name="custom" value=""> -->
<input type="image" style="width: 144px;" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

What should I change?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your markup looks okay. Can you clarify what you mean when you say "I won't get bound to ship something physical!"? PayPal just processes the payment for you and credits your account when it is verified. Its up to you to take extra steps, like shipping something physical or granting download access to digital media for example. If you clarify more what you mean, we might be able to help.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your question! When I receive payments thru PayPal Website Payments, I receive the payment as "Goods Payment" so that requires me to ship out something physical to the buyer's address, or he can dispute! If I receive the payment as "Services Payment" I won't have to ship anything to his shipping address, just email/etc the paid content! Clear now? :)

Comment: Yeah, I get what you mean now but someone beat me to the answer. As long as it worked out for you, that's all that matters I guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add this setting  `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ITEMCATEGORYm`

From Paypal Docs:

> Indicates whether an item is digital or physical. For digital goods, this field is required and must be set to Digital. You can specify up to 10 payments, where n is a digit between 0 and 9, inclusive, and m specifies the list item within the payment; except for digital goods, which only supports single payments. These parameters must be ordered sequentially beginning with 0 (for example L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ITEMCATEGORY0, L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ITEMCATEGORY1). It is one of the following values:

Digital
Physical
This field is available since version 65.1.

Comment: So I only have to add `<input type="hidden" name="L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ITEMCATEGORYm" value="Digital">` to the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

According to PayPal, it's **not possible** to mark item as service (or digital) in PayPal Website Standard API. That's possible in Paypal Express Checkout though, as Scott mentioned above.

Here is the quote of a PayPal representative's comment on this matter:

> Unfortunately, PayPal Website Standard does not support Digital Goods.
>   You will have to use the Express Checkout in order to use the
>   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ITEMCATEGORY='Digital' to set it as Digital Goods.